# How to exit a tmpl loop in perl?

Tags: html, perl, loops

I use **html templates** in Perl to generate a dynamic website, my `Script1.pm` generates a table and sends it as tmpl_loop to the `template.tmpl` to show a table on the website.

This works pretty well so far, but as the table gets bigger than about 100,000 rows, the whole browser starts to lag.

Can I somehow set a counter to exit the tmpl loop after 10000 iterations?

Just making the table smaller in the script doesn't work cause I need it completed for an export file.

Comment: Are you using [HTML::Template](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Template)? It might be useful to add an example template to your question to show exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Pbk1303 Adding inline code formatting to words and phrases that aren't code (like "set a counter" and "tmpl loop after 10000 iterations") is not an improvement. Neither is adding bold to random words (like "html templates"). Please stop making edits like this.

Comment: Please confirm which template module you're using to get relevant answers *"html templates"* isn't definitive, and a couple of people have suggested what module you may be using

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using [Template::Toolkit](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template), you can use the special `loop` variable:

```
[% FOREACH match IN results %]
    [% LAST IF loop.count > 10000 %]
[% END %]
```

Note that `BREAK` is also an alias for `LAST`.

Answer (score 2):

Trim the data before sending it to the template in the first place.

For example, change

```
 $template->param(ROWS => \@rows);
```

to

```
 splice(@rows, 10_000);
 $template->param(ROWS => \@rows);
```

or

```
 my @truncated_rows = @rows[0 .. $#rows < 10_000 ? $#rows : 10_000];
 $template->param(ROWS => \@truncated_rows);
```

The latter is non-destructive, so if you need the entire set of rows for another purpose later in the program, they will still be available. (It seems fishy to continue processing after the output is rendered, but an update to the question seems to indicate this is a requirement.)